# How often are AWS owned CMKs rotated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms

AWS owns their own Customer Master Keys (CMKs) and uses them [by default to encrypt data at rest in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EncryptionAtRest.html). Are these AWS owned CMKs rotated? If so, what is the frequency of the rotations?

Answer (score 1):

From AWS document.

> AWS managed CMKs. You cannot manage key rotation for AWS managed CMKs. AWS KMS automatically rotates AWS managed CMKs every three years (1095 days).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html

Comment: I just realized that this answer is relevant for AWS managed CMKs, but not AWS owned CMKs. According to [this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#aws-managed-cmk), they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon [documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#aws-managed-cmk) that the key rotation schedule for AWS owned keys varies based upon the AWS service. The [KMS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html) further indicate to consult each service's *Encryption at Rest* topic for details on key rotation. For DynamoDB, the [Encryption at Rest topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EncryptionAtRest.html) does not provide any details on key rotation.

Comment: Even though this doesn't provide an answer for the question, this is still very helpful. Thank you @bmul